# How to apply process corners in HSPICE?

Tags: simulation, spice

How can I apply process corners (TT, SS, FF) to my simulation in HSPICE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `.ALTER` command, found in the [HSPICE Command Reference](http://www.ece.rochester.edu/courses/ECE222/hspice/hspice_cmdref.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get corner simulations, but without seeing your models we can only guess as to how it is implemented. Also, keep in mind that not every model supports corner simulations! The best advice I can give you is to read the documentation that came with your models - if corner or Monte Carlo simulation is available they will tell you how to access it.

Here are a few ways that I've seen process corners implemented (some of these I've seen using Spectre):

- Separate model files for each corner
- The models have different sections for each corner case that must be selected
- You edit the sigma values for the models in one of the include files.
- FF/SS corners are not defined but models still have statistical data for Monte Carlo